# Change to next available row when there is a conflict in shared workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have a workbook which is shared among multiple users.

There is a `Userform` which asks for data and stores it in the workbook. It generates a row number where the user will enter data.

When two users open the `Userform` at the same time and one submits the data before other, Excel shows the conflict to other user.

Instead it should go to the next row and save the data. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Excel has not been designed for simultaneous editing by multiple users. Although shared workbooks are possible, they have many limitations, the most annoying of which is that they will become corrupt eventually, show erratic behaviour and are impossible to troubleshoot.

If you need simultaneous edit access, consider a database like Access or SQL. You can still use Excel as a front end.

Comment: Hi. Can you please elaborate on how to do that? I am not able to understand.

Comment: As @teylyn mentioned, you can still use Excel forms for user interaction and then enter data into a Access database (although I'm not a big fan of Access as a database). Google something like "update access database via excel vba". Should give you enough examples of how to interact with Access database from Excel. Just as a side note: I wouldn't recommend using Access forms as they are not true forms

Comment: Hi @Zac Thanks for your reply. If you don't recommend Access then what do you think I should use?

Comment: It really depends on the size of your data. If you don't expect your data to be too large (as in grow over time) then Access is good enough. But if you expect your data set to grow over time then I would consider something like SQL database. You can still interact with the SQL database from Excel VBA (i.e. Update, Add, Delete .. etc) hence giving you the flexibility to still use Excel Froms

Answer (score 0):

Normally by doing a check if your row is different than blank like this:

```
indx = 1                       'this is the generated index of your row
If Cells(1, indx) <> "" Then   '1 is your column, in this case A
    indx = indx + 1
End If
```

But if you have multiple users accessing it the cell will not be updated in the second user worksheet, they are not synchronised and data entered by the 1st user remains invisible for the second up to the point when he reopens it.

Comment: Maybe you might consider moving that form and creating same thing in access?

Comment: Hi, So in acess I need to create the form and link it with excel so that data is entered in excel?

Comment: No, consider moving everything to Access. Access is a database and that can work with multiple users, data entered in Access forms would be stored in access database.

Comment: Okay. Thanks but I need to use excel only

Comment: Sure, no problem just forget about multiple user being able to edit data correctly :)

Comment: Yeah I know sharing workbook is a pain. But i have no other option